# C Code: Why would someone declare a variable and a pointer, then point the pointer to the address of that variable?

Tags: c, pointers

I have some 30 year old C code I'm trying to clean up, and I ran into something I don't know if I should change.  The code is like this:

```
MY_OBJ obj1;
MY_OBJ *obj2;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    obj2 = &obj1;
    ...
}
```

Then `obj1` is never referenced again.  Is there any reason to do this in C?  I am not completely new but some of the memory management is still fresh to me, and I don't want to mess anything up.  Would it be the same if I rewrite it and just declare `obj2` outright like:

```
MY_OBJ obj2;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I usually do `MY_OBJ obj[1] /* = {0} */;` to get an /*initialized*/ object and a pointer with a single declaration/definition. `obj` is the pointer (in most contexts), `*obj` (or `obj[0]`) is the object.

Comment: If you are SURE that obj1 is never referenced again it is probably some legacy forgotten code that you can remove.

Comment: But `obj2` is probably referenced, and `obj1` is accessed by passing a pointer around instead of the object itself. If `obj1` is a `struct`, then the *entire* `struct` would be passed to a function, but as `obj2`, just a pointer.

Comment: You need to examine how the pointer `obj2` is used later in the program. Since you haven't shown that, we can't really tell you whether your replacement makes sense.

Comment: It totally depends on the use case which we cannot see here. You should show us some lines of code that show how `obj2` is used. Maybe it's just weird code, hard to tell without seeing more. And, believe me, there is a lot of weird code in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

Your replacement is not the same.  `obj1` is an allocated thing, and it could be large, say 100's or 1000's of bytes.  But `obj2` is just a pointer, which takes up 4 bytes in many typical platforms.

In many programs, it is useful to pass around a pointer, and possibly update its value for a different thing like `obj1`, and not have to make copies of what could be a very large amount of memory.  Perhaps `obj1` is a default value, just to be safe, and a more meaningful value is provided from a file or network transaction.

**In short, there are definitely reasons the given code could make sense.**  And it also could be obsolete, depending on the history of the project.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would someone declare a variable and a pointer, then point the pointer to the address of that variable?

Because they want an object, and they want a pointer to that object.

We can't tell you whether they have a good reason for wanting a pointer to that object, because you haven't shown how the pointer is used. I can definitely think of good reasons to do this, but I have no way to guess whether they apply here.

> I am not completely new but some of the memory management is still fresh to me

Do you understand pointers?

If not, you are to all intents and purposes "completely new". Pointer manipulation is very common in idiomatic C.

Do you understand how this pointer is used later in the code? If not, you definitely shouldn't change it. Understanding what the code does now is a bare minimum pre-requisite for refactoring.

> Would it be the same if I rewrite it and just declare obj2 outright like

This comment is one of the reasons I'm worried you don't really understand pointers. A pointer to an object is not the same as the object. Since you haven't shown us anything about how the pointer is used later, we can't tell you whether this will basically be OK with slight syntactic changes, or whether it is completely unworkable.

Comment: This is the only answer (actually rather a very elaborate comment) that makes sense here. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a pointer around is not only cheaper because it's smaller, but also the only way to let a function modify the pointed struct, because all parameters are passed by value in C (i.e. copied). The only other way to change `obj1` would be to reference it as a global variable, and directly referencing global variables from functions is a bad idea.

The second thing to note is that a pointer must point to *something* in order to be useful: it can either be a statically allocated long-living global variable, or a dynamically allocated variable created by calling `malloc` at some point in your program. The first approach makes far more sense for variables which are long-lived, but if you wanted to get rid of `obj1`, this would have worked also:

```
// must remember to free this memory at some point
obj2 = malloc(sizeof *obj2);
```

Since the pointer is also global and this seems like a single-time initialization, it would make more sense to initialize it at the point of its declaration and mark it `const`:

```
MY_OBJ obj1;

// Initialize obj2 to &obj1 and mark it const so
// that it cannot point to anything else
// (this still allows you to dereference it 
// and modify the contents of the pointed struct)
MY_OBJ * const obj2 = &obj1;
```

Finally, note that passing `&obj1` around instead of `obj2` would also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some functions getting `MY_OBJ *` as parameter. If you remove `obj2` you should also write `&obj1` instead of all `obj2`s.